# Casting a Type does not work

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have the following classes:

```
// abstract
abstract class Module
{
    public Options Params;
}

abstract class Options { }

// implementation
class MyModule : Module
{
    public new MyOptions Params = new MyOptions();
}

class MyOptions : Options
{
    public string Param1;
}
```

and code:

```
var MyMod = new MyModule();
MyMod.Params.Param1 = "new value"; // ok

// convert
Module Mod = MyMod; // if use MyModule Mod - ok
if (Mod.Params as MyOptions != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("cast OK"); // not execute
}
```

Modules can be of different types (I don't know them), but it is always inherited from Module. I need to determine whether the field `Params` is instance(or implements) `MyOptions` and get value, if true it. I would be happy with any decisions.

Comment: When keyword `new` is used `Module.Params` is not replaced, but just hidden by `MyModule.Params`. In most cases this is not what programmer wants, and in most cases keyword `new` should not be used. Keywords `virtual`/`override` or `abstract`/`override` should be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding the `Options` field using the `new` keyword, thus it would only be accessible when called from `MyModule`.

There is no connection between `Module.Params` and `MyModule.Params`, and even though the runtime knows that `Mod` is a `MyModule`, it still gets the value from `Module.Params`, which is `null`.

See [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

If you want true inheritance, you'll need to use virtual methods (or in this case, virtual properties):

```
abstract class Module
{
    public abstract Options Params { get; set; }
}

class MyModule : Module
{
    private Options myParams = new MyOptions();
    public override Options Params
    {
        get { return myParams; }
        set { myParams = value; }
    }
}
```

---

```
var MyMod = new MyModule();
(MyMod.Params as MyOptions).Param1 = "new value";

Module Mod = MyMod;
if (Mod.Params as MyOptions != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("cast OK"); 
}
```

Comment: I delete keyword "new", nothing has changed :c

Comment: @fubogi That wouldn't change anything, you need to define the property as virtual/abstract. See the code I've attached.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `is`:

```
if(Mod.Params is MyOptions)
{
}
```

read about [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) operator.

It's always better to use `is` because you don't need to cast and check for null. Try it [here](http://ideone.com/xsrHsf)

Comment: (Mod.Params is MyOptions) returns false. Why is this happening?

Comment: @fubogi nope, tested try link in answer. It shows yes, so Params is MyOptions

Comment: @wudzid It works because you're calling it from `MyModule`, not `Module`.

Answer (score 0):

Mod is considered as Module, so Params is always Options. You should cast Mod first back to MyModule

Answer (score 0):

Also, logical and concise version:

```
abstract class Module
{
    public Options Params { get; protected set; }
}
abstract class Options { }

class MyModule : Module
{
    public MyOptions MyParams
    {
        get
        {
            if (Params == null) Params = new MyOptions();
            return Params as MyOptions;
        }
    }
}

class MyOptions : Options
{
    public string Param1;
}
```

using:

```
var MyMod = new MyModule();
MyMod.MyParams.Param1 = "new value";

// convert
Module Mod = MyMod;
var Params = Mod.Params as MyOptions;

if (Params != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Params.Param1);
}
```